# AngularJS: Removing HTML element from DOM, but not its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and I've got a doubt.

I have something like this:

```
<a href="#">
 <p>Hello World!</p>
</a>
```

I want to remove the anchor, but not its content. If I use ng-show/ng-hide, according to the condition it removes everything, the anchor and even the paragraph.

How can i remove just the anchor keeping the content displayed (but unlinked)?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest that you use a directive for this kind of thing.

Comment: why can't you remove it from template? or use `ng-if` or `ng-switch` You haven't provided any conditions

Comment: When you want it to happen? On page load, or you want to be able to  return element back on some condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ng-href and an expression:

```
<a ng-href="{{show()? '#' : ''}}">
 <p>Hello World!</p>
</a>
```

Comment: But the content (<p></p>) will remain linked, won't it? What i want is removing the anchor totally.

Comment: his answer will work... i was going to answer his, here's a plnkr related to this answer... http://plnkr.co/edit/bGn2csAF3JtZpEql9O9s?p=preview

Comment: The tag will remain there, but since the href attribute will be empty, there won't be any link. If you want to completely remove the anchor tag, then I recommend using a custom directive.

Answer (score 1):

*Might not be best approach.*

You can use

```
<a ng-if="condition == false">
 <p>Hello World!</p>
</a>    
<p ng-if="condition == true">Hello World!</p>
```

In place of `ngIf` you can use `ngShow` or `ngHide`

Comment: Yep, it occurred to me, but i also thought it may not be the best approach... Anyway, if there is not any best answer, that one will be what i'll use.